# How do i keep my program going?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

Hey guys im making a game to help me study for finals. It is basically flash cards. I want the program to print out my question and answer by randomly selecting one. The thing is i dont want he same random number to be picked twice. how do i make sure the same number isn't picked twice till im out of questions? I am trying to make each random number be stored in blacklist so i can just check if the number is already in there before the program prints.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Games {

        static ArrayList<Integer> blacklist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static int number;
        static String[][] yes = {{"Apostolic Orgin", "Comes form the apostles"},
            {"Biblical inerrancy", "the doctrine that the books are free from error reading the truth"},
            {"Divine Inspiration", "the assistance the holy spirit gave the authors or the bible so they could write"},
            {"fundamentalist approach", "interpretation of the bible and christian doctrine based on the literal meaning og bible's word"}, {"pentateuch", "first 5 books of old testament"}};

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Printer(pickQuestion(), pickAnswer());
        }

        public static int RandomNumber(int i) {
            int c;
            Random r = new Random();
            c = r.nextInt(i);
            return c;

        }

        public static void Printer(String question, String answer) {
            System.out.println("Question: " + question);
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
        }

        public static String pickQuestion() {
            number = RandomNumber(yes.length);
            return yes[number][0];
        }

        public static String pickAnswer() {
            return yes[number][1];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to pre-shuffle the list of questions, either messing with the question and answer arrays directly, or by creating an array of integers from 1 to n where is the number of questions, shuffling that, and then loading the "card" in the position pointed to by that value in the array. 
That is, create 
[1,2,3,4,5]
Shuffle:
[5,1,3,4,2]
And load question 5, then question 1, etc.

This latter option would make a few things easier, not least of which is debugging!

Creating the array in order is a trivial for loop, and there are plenty of standard algorithms for shuffling too. 
[Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)